# Не удается вывести коллекцию

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть две модели заказ и поле.

```
public class Pole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pole> Poles { get; set; }
    public Purchase()
    {
    Poles = new List<Pole>();
    }

}
```

Есть действие в контроллере
    [HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult AddPole( Pole pole, int? id)
    {
        Purchase purchase = db.Purchases.Find(id);

        purchase.Poles.Add(pole);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

И соответствующее представление

```
 @model CRM.Models.Pole
 @{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Поле")
<br />
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
<br /><br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, "Значение")
<br />
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
}
```

Проблема в том,что при попытке вывести элементы из списка Poles ничего не выводится.Думаю,что просто не добавляется pole в purchase.Poles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в контекст работы с базой надо добавить:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Purchase>()
      .HasMany<Pole>(a => a. Poles)
      .WithRequired(a => a.Purchase)
      .HasForeignKey(a => a.PurchaseId)
```

в моделе Purchase исправить

```
public ICollection<Pole> Poles { get; set; }
```

на

```
public virtual ICollection<Pole> Poles { get; set; }
```

в модель Pole добавить:

```
public virtual Purchase Purchase {get;set;}
public int PurchaseId {get;set;}
```

Comment: Спасибо.А что за поле a.Order?

Comment: @D.Ult сейчас поправлю :) Копипаст из моего проекта